# Computing dask delayed objects stored in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dask, dask-delayed

I am looking for the best way to compute many `dask` `delayed` obejcts stored in a dataframe. I am unsure if the `pandas` dataframe should be converted to a `dask` dataframe with `delayed` objects within, or if the `compute` call should be called on all values of the `pandas` dataframe.

I would appreciate any suggestions in general, as I am having trouble with the logic of passing `delayed` object across nested for loops.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import hypergeom
from dask import delayed, compute

steps = 5
sample = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(5, 100, num=steps)]
enr_df = pd.DataFrame()

for N in sample:
    enr = []
    for i in range(20):
        k = np.random.randint(1, 200)
        enr.append(delayed(hypergeom.sf)(k=k, M=10000, n=20, N=N, loc=0))
    enr_df[N] = enr
```

I cannot call `compute` on this dataframe without applying the function across all cells like so: `enr_df.applymap(compute)` (which I believe calls `compute` on each value individually).

However if I convert to a `dask` dataframe the `delayed` objects I want to compute are layered in the `dask` dataframe structure:

```
enr_dd = dd.from_pandas(enr_df, npartitions=1)
enr_dd.compute()
```

And the computation output I expect does not proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a list of delayed objects into `dask.compute`

```
results = dask.compute(*list_of_delayed_objects)
```

So you need to get a list from your Pandas dataframe.  This is something you can do with normal Python code.

Comment: Right, will performance be best if all delayed objects are stored in a list, `dask.compute()` is called on this, and then reformatted? Even if the list is very large?

Comment: The performance will be no different.  Dask has around a 300us overhead per task, regardless of how the task is presented.